# ComplexPlot3D and essential singularities

Tags: plotting, complex

I am trying to understand the behavior of the functions

$$ f(z) = e^\frac{1}{z} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{1}{f(z)} = \frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{z}}
$$

in the neighborhood of $z=0$.

---

From the power series representation of $e^{1/z}$, we know that $f$ has an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) at $z=0$. Because $1/f(z) = f(-z)$ in this case, we know that $1/f$ is simply $f$ reflected about the origin, so $1/f$ should match the behavior of $f$ near $0$. In particular, $1/f$ also has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

---

In the newly released Mathematica 12, there is a function called `ComplexPlot3D`. Using the information on the [documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot3D.html), I was able to plot $g(z) = z$ and $h(z)=1/z$, as well as changing the plot range via the additional argument `PlotRange → {0,100}`.

This worked perfectly for $z$ and $1/z$ but **only generated an empty plot with axes** for $e^\frac{1}{z}$ or $1/\left(e^\frac{1}{z}\right)$.

I attempted to plot the same functions with different ranges using `PlotRange` but this did not change anything. This is the input I used:

```
 ComplexPlot3D[e^(1/z), {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}]
```

The problem shouldn't be the range, as $e^\frac{1}{z}$ should [attain every value in $\mathbb{C}$ (except $0$) infinitely often in any neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem#The_theorems) of $z=0$ ... there should be some points on the plot that show up, regardless of what `PlotRange` we choose.

---

So, my question is:

> Why does `ComplexPlot3D` not work for $f(z) = e^\frac{1}{z}$? Is `ComplexPlot3D`perhaps incompatible with essential singularities? Do I have some incorrect syntax or other mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is your lowercase `e`. That symbol is undefined in Mathematica. Either use Esc ee Esc, `E`, or `Exp`. The following seems to work fine:

```
ComplexPlot[Exp[1/z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]
```

[image: Complex Plot.]

Comment: Thank you! I feel a bit silly knowing it's such a simple mistake ("$e$ is uppercase in mathematica"). That said, I do find it strange that $e$, $i$ (which are conventionally lowercase in pretty much all other math contexts) are uppercase in mathematica ..

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yeah, I agree. My guess is that it has to do with their design style where all built-in functions start with a capital letter, and they continued that to i and e, maybe? I often use Esc ee Esc and Esc ii Esc to make them seem more normal.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: Requiring `E` and `I` is totally consistent with the rule that all built-in Mathematica names begin with upper-case letters (or with `$` followed by an upper-case letter). The doubled-letter symbol you get with Esc ee Esc is just a shortcut for `E`. Of course you could avoid the whole issue by using the exponential function, as in `Exp[1/z]`.

Comment: @murray But not `exp[1/z]` of course. :)

Comment: I use `i` as an iterator or an index all the time. IMO it’s good they stayed consistent with their naming conventions.